# asp.net mvc CRUD add/delete a category/product

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ive been stuck on this learning more with CRUD in asp.net mvc. im able to view the category list, view the products list and add just product. I cant figure out how to add to the category and delete from category and product list

1st i wasnt able to view my category list and was about to fix that from data i manually added to the table.

```
 public GenericUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new GenericUnitOfWork();

    public List<SelectListItem> GetCategory()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var cat = _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Category>().GetAllRecords();
        foreach (var item in cat)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.CategoryId.ToString(), Text = item.CategoryName });
        }
        return list;
    }
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Categories()
    {


        return View(_unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Category>().GetAllRecords());

    }
    public ActionResult AddCategory(Tbl_Category tbl)
    {

        _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Category>().Add(tbl);
        return UpdateCategory(0);

    }



    public ActionResult UpdateCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        CategoryDetail cd;
        if (categoryId != null)
        {
            cd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CategoryDetail>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Category>().GetFirstorDefault(categoryId)));
        }
        else
        {
            cd = new CategoryDetail();

        }


        return View("UpdateCategory", cd);

    }
    public ActionResult CategoryEdit(int catId)
    {
        return View(_unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Category>().GetFirstorDefault(catId));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CategoryEdit(Tbl_Category tbl)
    {


        _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Category>().Update(tbl);
        return RedirectToAction("Categories");
    }


    public ActionResult Product()
    {
        return View(_unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Product>().GetProduct());
    }
    public ActionResult ProductEdit(int productId)
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryList = GetCategory();
        return View(_unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Product>().GetFirstorDefault(productId));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductEdit(Tbl_Product tbl, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string pic = null;
        if (file != null)
        {
            pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImg/"), pic);
            // file is uploaded
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        tbl.ProductImage = file != null ? pic : tbl.ProductImage;
        tbl.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Product>().Update(tbl);
        return RedirectToAction("Product");
    }
    public ActionResult ProductAdd()
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryList = GetCategory();
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductAdd(Tbl_Product tbl, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string pic = null;
        if (file != null)
        {
            pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImg/"), pic);
            // file is uploaded
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        tbl.ProductImage = pic;
        tbl.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Product>().Add(tbl);
        return RedirectToAction("Product");
    }
```

here is the updating category view to add a category to the list

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Breadcrumbs-->

<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item ">Categories</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Add New Category</li>


</ol>
<!-- DataTables Example -->
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
        Add New Category

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCategory", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {


            @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryId)*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Category Id</label>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CategoryId, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter category Id", required = "required", autofocus = "autofocus" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Category Name</label>

                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CategoryName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter category Name", required = "required", autofocus = "autofocus" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CategoryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <a onclick="window.history.back();" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />



        }
    </div>
        </div>
```

trying to delete category "Category edit view"

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="../Admin/Categories">Category</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Edit</li>
    </ol>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryId)

    @{
        List<SelectListItem> data = ViewBag.CategoryList;
    }

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.CheckBox("IsActive")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsDelete, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.CheckBox("IsDelete")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDelete, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    }


</div>
```

trying to delete product but, able to add product and view the list

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
     Breadcrumbs
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="../Admin/Product">Product</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Edit Product</li>
    </ol>
</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div>
            <h4>Product</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            @{
                List<SelectListItem> data = ViewBag.CategoryList;
            }
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, data, "---Select---", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.CheckBox("IsActive")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsDelete, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsDelete, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDelete, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsDelete)

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifiedDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModifiedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModifiedDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductImage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsFeatured, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.CheckBox("IsFeatured")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsFeatured, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem, what happens when you delete the category or product?

Comment: It will save that when i click the delete check box but, won’t delete from the table

Comment: I cant see where you are trying to delete anything in the controller, is is a soft delete?